# Windows Sever 2008 R2 Trust Issue

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, active-directory

I am currently running my network over a Cisco Meraki site to site VPN network.  I currently have 4 sites, and all sites are connected to the site to site VPN and working without issue.

I am trying to setup a domain trust with one of my sites but for whatever reason when I try to setup the trust with the 4th location it wont connect telling me that "The operation failed. The error is: The specified account already exists."

I have looked in the active directory to see if either of the server names are in each others active directory and I do not see them (I have even searched for it and no luck).  I have conditional forwarders setup for each of the sites.  I have done a decent amount of googling on this issue and cant seem to find any resolution.  I am hoping that someone else has experienced this issue and can explain to me how to resolve the issue.

To recap:

1. I have 4 sites that are all connected to a site to site vpn (working flawlessly)
2. I am trying to create a domain trust with a specific server
3. 3 of the 4 domain trusts connected to this server without issue
4. I have setup the conditional forwarders inside of DNS for all the servers. ( I have also setup each server as a forwarder in DNS properties)
5. Getting error "The operation failed. The error is: The specified account already exists."
6. The server OS is Server 2008 R2

Hopefully I didnt leave out any information needed, but if I have, please ask and I will provide it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. check If netbios domain names of all the domains involved are unique
2. check functional level. Maybe the last one is operating its forest/domain in w2k mode ?
3. **check if You do not have by mistake something like this:

   - domainA.local {Netbios domainA} <-trust_You_try_to_establish-> domainB.local {Netbios domainB}
   - but unfortunatly in domainA You have a computer with name "domainB". (or vice versa)
   - search objects with these names in both domains.**
4. check if one of domain name is not on this list : http://support.microsoft.com/kb/266633 however it applies to w2k - w2k3 but who knows.
5. try to create a one way trust -> see if it works in one direction ?

the root cause has been marked BOLD. Searching one of the domains a computer with same name as the other domain netbios name was found.

Comment: I will check the netbios names and the functional levels are the same on all servers which is Windows Server 2008 R2 and will try the one way direction.  I will report back shortly.  Thank you for the quick response.

Comment: Ok so to update quickly, Server A (the local server) can setup a 1 way trust with ServerB ( the external server).  If I try to setup the one way trust from Server B to Server A, it gives me the account already exist bit again.  Does this narrow it down to netbios for sure?

Comment: Yes that narrows the search for object with the same name in one domain. Try to find them / check if there are no netbios names conflicts. The Trust objects are crated in the "System" OU just on top of AD structure. Run active directory users and computers -> view -> advanced features and You will see the "System" container. It is most likely na netbios domain name conflict or You have a computer with same name as other domain netbios name.

Comment: How should I search, Im using the active directory search tool and its not coming up.

Comment: If You are using search from "Active Directory Users and Computers" You probably only searching by default not for all objects. You need to do an advanced search to find all types of objects: howto here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa996205%28v=exchg.65%29.aspx

Comment: ps. I used this syntax to get all objects with the same name as the other domain netbios (cn=name_of_trusted_domain_netbios*) - the * is important because the object probably has na $ at the end. also make sure You search the right domain :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12353/discussion-between-bartlomiej-zarzecki-and-mike-k)

Comment: Bartłomiej Zarzecki told me to use (cn=NetBIOSNAME*) on the troublesome server.  It came back with the troublesome name, once I deleted it, everything worked!  Much props to him.