# Establish Trust Between Two Active Directory Domains with a Common Root

Tags: active-directory, domain-controller, windows-server-2022, trust-relationship

In my lab environment, I'd like to create a trust relation between two Active Directory domains that share a common root. One is `home.acme.com` and the other is `work.acme.com`. When I create both domains as separate forests and then use the AD Trust UI flow to create a forest wide two way trust in both domains for forest wide authentication, I get an error

*The operation failed. The error is: The specified account already exists.*

I'm wondering if I'm getting this error because both domains `home.acme.com` and `work.acme.com` contain the same root `acme.com` yet I created them as separate forests. If so, what flow should I use to create the the two domains? Should I create a domain `acme.com` and make `home.acme.com` and `work.acme.com` subdomains or can I somehow get away with only creating the two domains I'm interested in `home.acme.com` and `work.acme.com`.

Thanks!
Chris

Comment: From https://serverfault.com/questions/565628/windows-sever-2008-r2-trust-issue. I had a computer in work.acme.com named HOME. After deleting that I no longer get that error.

Comment: we do usually not provide learning materials. Best Practice is always creating subdomains of anykind like Munich.mycompany.local to not get in trouble having the same name anywhere and at this point there will usually no trouble at all

Comment: This shouldn't prevent you from establishing trust. At least, in Windows Server 2003 it did not; similar setup even worked in production.